# dojo module append .min.js to module request

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, js-amd

Is there a way to configure the dojo module loader to append .min.js instead of just .js?

My directory structure:

- dist/

  - components

    - some-component.min.js

My config:

```
window.dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    packages: [
        {
            name: 'my-module',
            location: "https://my-domain.com/dist/"
        }
    ]
};
```

When I require that component

`require(['my-module/components/some-component'])`

it sends this request

`"https://my-domain.com/dist/components/some-component.js"`,

which is missing the `".min"`.

Is there any way to have more granular control over how dojo constructs the requests for modules?